# TableViewCellContentView is narrower than TableView on iPad, While the TableView is created by code

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ipad

I want the TableViewCellContentView has the same width with TableView, Here's the code:

```
#import "ViewController.h"
@interface ViewController ()<UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate>
@property(strong) UITableView* mainTableView;
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];
  _mainTableView = [[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 20, CGRectGetWidth([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds), CGRectGetHeight([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds)-20)];
  _mainTableView.delegate = self;
  _mainTableView.dataSource = self;
  [self.view addSubview:_mainTableView];
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *SimpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableIdentifier";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:SimpleTableIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier: SimpleTableIdentifier];
}
cell.textLabel.text = @"111fewfwFwfrg";
cell.accessoryView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"me_today_arrow.png"]];
return cell;
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell* cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    //(lldb) po cell
    //<UITableViewCell: 0x13dd22bf0; frame = (0 220; 768 44); text = '111fewfwFwfrg'; autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0x13dd1cf30>>

    //(lldb) po cell.contentView
    //<UITableViewCellContentView: 0x13c6521a0; frame = (0 0; 711 43.5); opaque = NO; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x13c6594b0>; layer = <CALayer: 0x13c6546a0>>
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 10;
}
@end
```

and here's the image:
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/QK6a8.jpg

The lldb says the frame of TableViewCellContentView is (0 0; 711 43.5),the x value is 0 so there might be padding in the TableViewCell, but I can't find any method to set it. BTW, it works fine on iPhone.

Anyone can help me solve the problem?Thank you.

Comment: Is it the same when in both landscape and portrait mode?

Comment: Hi @zcui93 , yes it is.

Answer (score 0):

In viewdidload try:

[self.tableView setContentInset:UIEdgeInsetsZero];

Comment: hi @iSaalis , I inset  [_mainTableView setContentInset:UIEdgeInsetsZero]; before _mainTableView.delegate = self; , the problem still exists.